# cucumber ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: activerecord, cucumber

The exception I am getting is "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base".  I am really on the deep end of the pool (no pun intended) with this one.  I really don't understand the connection and connection pool handling, even as much as I have studied this problem.  I'm assuming this might be scope related inside of Cucumber, but I do not know.  Any and all assistance is appreciated.

Here are the details:

The exception occurs when I perform a count from a Then clause:

```
WorkTable.where('? is not null',col['COLUMN_NAME']).count
```

It does not occur if I send the sql directly through the connection:

```
WorkTable.connection.select_all(st.encode('utf-8')).first['nulls']
```

My scenario reads as follows:

```
  Scenario: CompanyMaster test for null value
    Given table dbo.base_table in stage
    Then these columns are expected to be not null
      | COLUMN_NAME                         | nulls |
      | id                                  | 0 |
      | company_name                        | 0 |
```

I establish my class in my env.rb:

```
class WorkTable < ActiveRecord::Base
end

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML.load_file(yaml)  # yaml is database.yml file name
```

I establish my connection in a Given clause:

```
Given(/^table (\w+)\.?([\w_]+) in (\w+)(?: as (\w+))?$/) do |schema,name,env,id|
  @sc_name = schema_file_name(schema,name)
  WorkTable.logger.info title_line("* Active table(#{@sc_name}) *")
  case id
    #  ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[env]
    ...
    else
      WorkTable.table_name = @sc_name
      WorkTable.establish_connection(env.to_sym)
      # ary = get_tables(WorkTable,schema:schema)
      # expect( ary.any?{|s| s.casecmp(name)==0 } ).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

I execute my test in a Then clause:

```
Then(/^these columns are expected to be not null$/) do |columns|
  # expected is an instance of Cucumber::Ast::Table
  WorkTable.logger.info title_line('Columns cannot be null')

  results = []
  columns.hashes.each {|col|
    results << {
        'COLUMN_NAME' => col['COLUMN_NAME'],
        'nulls' => WorkTable.where('? is not null',col['COLUMN_NAME']).count.to_s
    }
  }
  columns.diff!(results,surplus_row: false)
end
```

It is the WorkTable.where that throws the "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base".  Again, if I use the WorkTable.connection method, I do not get it.  Also, it executes fine if I copy all the *function* code to single ruby script.

I see the following when I "pp WorkTable.connection":

```
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter version: 4.2.2, mode: dblib, azure: false>
```

And I see the following when I "pp WorkTable.connection_pool":

```
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x42f5238
 @automatic_reconnect=true,
 @available=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Queue:0x42f4f20
   @cond=
    #<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x42f4ed8
     @cond=
      #<ConditionVariable:0x42f4de8
       @waiters=[],
       @waiters_mutex=#<Mutex:0x42f4d58>>,
     @monitor=
      #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x42f5238 ...>>,
   @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x42f5238 ...>,
   @num_waiting=0,
   @queue=[]>,
 @checkout_timeout=5,
 @connections=
  [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter version: 4.2.2, mode: dblib, azure: false>],
 @mon_count=0,
 @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x42f51c0>,
 @mon_owner=nil,
 @reaper=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x42f51a8
   @frequency=nil,
   @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x42f5238 ...>>,
 @reserved_connections=
  #<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x42f4fc8
   @backend=
    {16931712=>
      #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter version: 4.2.2, mode: dblib, azure: false>},
   @default_proc=nil>,
 @size=5,
 @spec=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x42f55c8
   @adapter_method="sqlserver_connection",
   @config=
    {:host=>"server_name",
     :database=>"mssb_stg",
     :encoding=>"utf-8",
     :adapter=>"sqlserver",
     :timeout=>5000}>>
```

Ruby 1.9.3, activerecord (4.2.0), activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.2), and cucumber (1.3.18).  And sql server 2014 [this has been a bugger for me].

Thank you for you time and consideration.
dvn

**== Additional detail ==**

Ignore the sql-server reference.  I get the same exception when I reconfigure to work with SqLite.  So it is not related to db platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your env.rb, conf in supports, it seems you are making connections in steps, ideally you should do it in `before_scenario` or `before feature` file rather than per steps.

It could be possible after steps your connection is not working properly.

Comment: I establish the connections in steps for two main reasons: a) I thought that was the correct place, and b) it is the proper place in this situation.  When I state "in stage" in the Given, it is "stage" that is identifies the database.yml environment I want to connect to.  That can change from scenario to scenario.  So I do it in the step.  Thanks for the info.  I never considered the hooks before, but that will clean things up in other applications.